# How do I create a menu bootstrap responsible for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I need a model for a site that has a menu made with bootstrap responsive.

You can help me with an example please?

I tried several variations but I realize I have to do to make this site a menu as such

www.dg-design.ch

Comment: Do you want a plug in or are trying to add the code yourself? This is important to figure out your approach. Need more information to facilitate

Comment: Great starter WP framework that uses bootstrap: https://roots.io/sage/

Comment: I like that page thanks for sharing... I am definitely going to use that as a jumping point!!

Answer (score 1):

**The HTML:**

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="site-navigation-inner col-sm-12">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            <?php if( get_header_image() != '' ) : ?>

                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>"  height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a>
                </div><!-- end of #logo -->

            <?php endif; // header image was removed ?>

            <?php if( !get_header_image() ) : ?>

                <div id="logo">
                    <span class="site-name"><a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span>
                </div><!-- end of #logo -->

            <?php endif; // header image was removed (again) ?>

            </div>
                <?php sparkling_header_menu(); ?> // <--The issue is here call to your menu instead
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

**The CSS:**

```
/* Clearing floats */
.clear:before,
.clear:after,
.site-header:before,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:before,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:before,
.site-footer:after,
.home-widget-area:before {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.clear:after,
.site-header:after {
  clear: both;
}
/* =Navigation
----------------------------------------------- */

.site-content [class*="navigation"] a {
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.paging-navigation {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.site-content [class*="navigation"] a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #DA4453;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.more-link {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.single .nav-links {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous {
  float: left;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.nav>li>a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #363636;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #F5F7FA;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
  color: #DADADA;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 13px 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-default {
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #DA4453;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #DA4453;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #656D78;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #DADADA;
  }
}
.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #636467;
}
.dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  border: none;
}
.dropdown-menu>.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
  background-color: #DA4453;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu .divider {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.nav.navbar-nav {
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

**Change 1**

Figured it out: You need a plugin called Navwalker the functions call to it to support wpBootstrap Navbars below is the link to the code and the call to function to get you running:

**The PHP**

```
<?php
/**
 * Load custom nav walker
 */
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/navwalker.php';
?>
```

Here is the link to Navwalker.php:

GitHub URI: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Just add it to your wp-content => themes => < YOUR THEME > => inc => navwaker.php

**Change 3**
Also: 
Change code below to your call to header_menu
**From:**

```
<?php
    ...
    sparkling_header_menu();
    ...
?>
```

**To:**

```
<?php
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
?>
```

Try this and see if it works!! let me know if it does not and I will fix it

Happy Coding!!

See it in action at: https://soldierupdesigns.com/blog/

download the Sparkling WP-theme at: https://wordpress.org/themes/sparkling/

Comment: Fatal Error:Call to undefined function sparkling_header_menu()

Comment: Give me about 20 minutes and I will get that function for you

Answer (score 1):

If you are converting your bootstrap html to a wordpress template use this navwalker for menu 
https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker